# invalid relational operator when using Java.util.Date.getTime() in Oracle Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle

Pretty much as the title says, I am trying to put a simple Java time value into my SQL for Oracle but I get the below error when the code runs the query.

> Exception:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid
> relational operator

```
Long theTime = new java.util.Date().getTime();
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT...");
...
sql.append(" WHERE from_date <= "+new java.sql.Timestamp(theTime));

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql.toString());
```

How can I resolve this exception?

**Additional information**
I should add that for reasons unknown, when using this against Oracle 19c (does't happen on 12c) we are having an issue with PreparedStatement.

This line 'hangs' for 3 hours, before running and returning results, hence why I'm suing the example above.

```
StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer("SELECT...");
...
sql.append(" WHERE from_date <= ?");
PreparedStatement ps = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql.toString()); // Hangs here for 3 hours!
```

Thanks in advance

K.

Comment: Use `?` parameter placeholders and pass arguments via `setXxx()`. First and foremost to stop being vulnerable to SQL injection (look that up).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` and/or other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. - Hi Ole, thanks for that, I have added additional comment o the question, should have mentioned this is all because for some reason in Oracle 19c, the PreparedStatement hangs for a long period, before returning results.